# Don't leave Parent Page after adding a new Child object

Tags: custom-object, relationships, childrelationship, child-to-parent

I have an object: Parent and an object: Child on my SalesForce, the issue is that when I am on my parent object and I click on 'create new child' then I create this child, after confirming that child creation salesforce send me to the child Page.

Do you know how to stay on parent page after creating a child object ? It's going to be a bit annoying if I have to create 15 child and I have to go back to parent page manually after each new child creation.

Thank you a lot for your answers,

Oneal

Comment: I don't have any idea about standard way, but you can create a VF page and then on click of save redirect to parent page.

Comment: Please also make sure to note whether you are in Classic or Lightning Experience and whether you're using standard functionality or customization.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to create a screen flow allowing for multiple child record creation without leaving the parent record:

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/flow-builder/flow-builder-screens